# Возможно ли поймать поля ввода на стороннем сайте?

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Собственно сабж. Конкретнее: есть свой сайт, на нем нужно написать такой скрипт, который будет вписывать определенный пользователем текст в textarea на другом сайта. Например livejournal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если только браузером будете отслеживать. Через php и js вряд-ли получится.

Answer (score 1):

Если второй сайт не ваш, то никак. Для подобного только плагин для браузера

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите куда ведет action формы на том сайте где стоит поле, и создайте свою форму с таким же адресом, и если там нет проверок реферала и тд, а это в livejournal вряд ли, то отправите текст прям туда : )

да и реферала подделать можно.